# WebStorm built in terminal colors don't get updated once theme has been changed from black to white

Tags: terminal, ide, phpstorm, webstorm, color-scheme

I frequently switch between black and white themes of WebStorm when working in different day/night light conditions. One thing that always annoys me is that I have to manually close terminal in order for it to switch colors.

[image]

That's the only part of the interface that doesn't update automatically. Looks like a bug to me.

Is there any way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue, please follow [IDEA-170747](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170747) for updates; unfortunately no workarounds exist for this issue - except for re-opening terminal tabs after switching UI theme